# Is there a Python equivalent of R way of finding last non-NAT date in prior week

Tags: python, r, pandas

My sample dataset looks like as below:

```
txn_time = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3],
                       'Start_Date':['2017-08-25','2017-08-25','2017-09-01','2017-09-08','2017-09-08','2017-09-08','2017-09-15','2017-09-22','2017-09-22'],
                       'Invoice':['2017-08-26','2017-08-27',pd.NaT,'2017-09-09','2017-09-10','2017-09-10','2017-09-16','2017-09-17',pd.NaT]})
```

For every ID and Start_Date, I want to find the last non-NaT transaction from previous week.
For example -  for ID 1 and for Start_Date 2017-09-18, previous week (2017-09-01) has only NaT date in Invoice column, I will look into the previous to previous week now which is 2017-08-25. In this week, the last non-NaT date is 2017-08-27

I can do this in R easily using data tables and joins as below:

```
setDT(df)[,grp_week:=.GRP,keyby=.(ID,Start_Date)]
lookup <- df[!is.na(Invoice), last(Invoice), by = grp_week + 1L]
df[, last_dat := lookup [.SD, on = "grp_week", V1, roll = Inf]]
```

Is there any equivalent and quicker way of doing the same in Python ?

The expected output is as below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'Start_Date':['2017-08-25','2017-08-25','2017-09-01','2017-09-08','2017-09-08','2017-09-08','2017-09-15','2017-09-22','2017-09-22'],'Invoice':['2017-08-26','2017-08-27',pd.NaT,'2017-09-09','2017-09-10','2017-09-10','2017-09-16','2017-09-17',pd.NaT],'output':[pd.NaT,pd.NaT,'2017-08-27','2017-08-27','2017-08-27',pd.NaT,'2017-09-10',pd.NaT,pd.NaT]})
```

What I have been able to achieve so far ?

```
txn_time=txn_time.reset_index()
txn_time=txn_time.rename(columns={'index':'look_up'})
lut=txn_time.groupby(['idx'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x:x['Invoice'].last_valid_index()).dropna()
lut=lut.rename(columns=str).rename(columns={'None':'look_up'})
lut=pd.merge(lut,txn_time.loc[:,['ID','look_up','Invoice']],on=['look_up','look_up']).drop(['look_up'],axis=1)
lut['idx']=lut['idx']+1
pd.merge(txn_time,lut,on=['ID','idx'],how='left')
```

This code gives the last value in previous week (irrespective of the fact that it is NaT). For ID 1 and for Start_Date 2017-09-18, it returns NaT, but my requirement is it should take non-NaT value from most recent previous week and return 2017-08-27

Comment: I meant NaT from Pandas. Let me know if that helps